# Droppable zone for items with js

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm trying to make a drop area for draggable items, so I have this html code - together with css and javascript code:

```js
const l = text => console.log("Log: " + text)
let dropArea = document.getElementById('drop-place')

dropArea.addEventListener('dragenter', function() {
  hovered();
});

dropArea.addEventListener('dragleave', function() {
  setDefault();
});

dropArea.addEventListener('dragover',  function() {
  hovered();
});

dropArea.addEventListener('drop',  function() {
  setDefault();
});

function hovered (e) {
  let evt = window.event; 
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation();
  dropArea.classList.add('hovered');
}  

function setDefault () {
  dropArea.classList.remove('hovered');
}
```

```css
.drag-items
{
    cursor: pointer;
}

#drop-place  
{
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #9DC88D;
    width: 600px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#drop-place.hovered
{
    border: 2px dotted rgb(19, 83, 41) ;
}    

.drop-place__title  
{
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<div class="wrapperr">
    <ul class="drag-items">
        <li draggable="true">item 1</li>
        <li draggable="true">item 2</li>
        <li draggable="true">item 3</li>
        <li draggable="true">item 4</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="drop-place">
        <span class="drop-place__title">Drop here</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've added this tag `<span class="drop-place__title">Drop here</span>` into the `#drop-place` as a title! 
All drag events work fine, but if cursor falls or crosses `.drop-place__title` drag events (leave and enter) begin to work, that is why the class for hovered `#drop-place` toggles and then untoggles, so that `#drop-place` begins to ruffle or blink!
So, How  can I fix this? 
The attempt to make `::before` or `::after` pseudo classes with content instead the `span` works well, so that `#drop-place` doesn't ruffle or blink, but it isn`t comfortable for me, maybe there's another way to make it work correctly
Thanks !

Comment: It will be gr8 not to do anything (addclass "hovered") during the over event

Answer (score 0):

Hurray! I've found the way!
When I added drag events for parent `#drop-place`, js also added them for all child elements, so I only add

```
.drop-place__title  
  {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
```

in css, now I can also delete `hovered();` during the over event in js!

It works !

```js
const l = text => console.log("Log: " + text)
let dropArea = document.getElementById('drop-place')

dropArea.addEventListener('dragenter', function() {
  hovered();
});

dropArea.addEventListener('dragleave', function() {
  setDefault();
});

dropArea.addEventListener('dragover',  function() {

});

dropArea.addEventListener('drop',  function() {
  setDefault();
});

function hovered (e) {
  let evt = window.event; 
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation();
  dropArea.classList.add('hovered');
}  

function setDefault () {
  dropArea.classList.remove('hovered');
}
```

```css
.drag-items
{
    cursor: pointer;
}

#drop-place  
{
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #9DC88D;
    width: 600px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#drop-place.hovered
{
    border: 2px dotted rgb(19, 83, 41) ;
}    

.drop-place__title  
{
    user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<div class="wrapperr">
    <ul class="drag-items">
        <li draggable="true">item 1</li>
        <li draggable="true">item 2</li>
        <li draggable="true">item 3</li>
        <li draggable="true">item 4</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="drop-place">
        <span class="drop-place__title">Drop here</span>
    </div>
</div>
```